# How to open webcam in opencv2.4.6.1 on ubuntu12.04?

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, ubuntu-12.04, webcam

I am using opencv2.4.6.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I am new to opencv and have been trying to understand the sample programs in the opencv docs. I am trying to work on a project which takes a picture from a USB webcam (Kinamax Night Vision Camera) and do some image processing on it. I came across a sample code that is shown below:

```
#include "cv.h" 
#include "highgui.h" 
#include <stdio.h>  
// A Simple Camera Capture Framework 
int main() 
{
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY );
if ( !capture ) {
 fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: capture is NULL \n" );
 getchar();
 return -1;
}
// Create a window in which the captured images will be presented
cvNamedWindow( "mywindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
// Show the image captured from the camera in the window and repeat
while ( 1 ) {
 // Get one frame
 IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
 if ( !frame ) {
   fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: frame is null...\n" );
   getchar();
   break;
 }
 cvShowImage( "mywindow", frame );
 // Do not release the frame!
 //If ESC key pressed, Key=0x10001B under OpenCV 0.9.7(linux version),
 //remove higher bits using AND operator
 if ( (cvWaitKey(10) & 255) == 27 ) break;
}
// Release the capture device housekeeping
cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvDestroyWindow( "mywindow" );
return 0;
}
```

On compiling using:

```
g++ trycam.c -o trycam `--cflags --libs opencv`
```

It gives no errors.
When I try to run it using : ./trycam Nothing shows up! Literally Nothing.

On searching google and some other posts in the stackoverflow community, I tried updating the libraries and install other dependencies like ffmpeg,GTK, Gstreamer,etc. I understand that the webcam I have connected via USB is not supported as per the list of webcams supported by linux opencv in the link [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome/OS). Even my default webcam that is in my HP Pavilion dv6000 is not opening.

Is there a way I could get around this? Kindly help me out.

Comment: What /dev name of your camera `/dev/video0`?

Comment: When I give ls /dev, I don't see the camera name or something like video0 at all. Pardon me if this is the basic, but please help me out.

Comment: I am now able to activate my default webcam in my laptop. 

I guess I was missing on some drivers. I installed it from the link https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kernel-bugs/2010-July/128364.html and now it works. However, my usb cam is not working. 

In ls /dev, I am able to find video0 now, but any idea how to work around with the usb webcam? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you USB camera name is `video0` try to change `cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY )` to `cvCaptureFromCAM(0)`